# Conditional statements in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I have below input in a text file and need to generate output in another file based on the logic.
Here is my input file:

```html
customerid|Dateofsubscription|Customercode|CustomerType|CustomerText
1001|2017-05-23|455|CODE|SPRINT56
1001|2017-05-23|455|DESC|Unlimited Plan
1001|2017-05-23|455|DATE|2017-05-05
1002|2017-05-24|455|CODE|SPRINT56
1002|2017-05-24|455|DESC|Unlimited Plan
1002|2017-05-24|455|DATE|2017-05-06
```

Logic:

```html
If  Customercode = 455
if( CustomerType = "CODE" )
     Val= CustomerText
if( CustomerType = "DESC" )
    Description = CustomerText
if( CustomerType = "DATE" )
     Date = CustomerText
```

Output:

```html
customerid|Val|Description|Date
1001|SPRINT56|Unlimited Plan|2017-05-05
1002|SPRINT56|Unlimited Plan|2017-05-06
```

Could you please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rawData = LOAD data;
filteredData = FILTER rawData BY (Customercode == 455);

--Extract and set Val/Description/Date based on CustomerText and 'null' otherwise
ExtractedData = FOREACH filteredData GENERATE
            customerId,
            (CustomerType == "CODE" ? CustomerText : null) AS Val,
            (CustomerType == "DESC" ? CustomerText : null) AS Description,
            (CustomerType == "DATE" ? CustomerText : null) AS Date;

groupedData = GROUP ExtractedData  BY customerId;

--While taking MAX, all 'nulls' will be ignored
finalData = FOREACH groupedData GENERATE
             group as CustomerId,
             MAX($1.Val) AS Val,
             MAX($1.Description) AS Description,
             MAX($1.Date) AS Date;

DUMP finalData;
```

I have specified the core logic. Loading, formatting and storage should be straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

Filter the input where customercode=455,generate the required 2 columns,then group by customerid and then use [BagToString](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/func.html#bagtostring)
.

```
B = FILTER A BY Customercode == 455;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE $0 as CustomerId,$4 as CustomerText;
D = GROUP C BY CustomerId;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE group AS CustomerId, BagToString(C.CustomerText, '|'); -- Note:This will generate 1001,SPRINT56|Unlimited Plan|2017-05-05 so,you will have to concat the first field with '|' and then concat the resulting field with the second field which is already delimited by '|'.
F = FOREACH E GENERATE CONCAT(CONCAT($0,'|'),$1);
DUMP F;
```